# Symfony form: filter collection with a parameter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony 3.4.

I have a form to edit some answers for a given country and I would need to edit these answers on a per category basis.

I have setup a filter in my entity but I don't know how to call this getter with a parameter from my form.

The dirty alternative would be to remove non required elements from my form in my controller but this is not ideal...

Here is my form:

```
<?php

namespace cwt\psmdbBundle\Form;

use cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity\CcdbServicesAnswers;
use cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity\countries;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class countriesCCDBServicesAnswersType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('AnswersOfCategory', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => CcdbServicesAnswersType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false,),
                'label' => false,
            ));    
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity\countries',
            'categoryID' => 1,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'cwt_psmdbbundle_countries';
    }
}
```

Here is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity;

use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * countries
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity\Repository\countriesRepository")
 */
class countries
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity\CcdbServicesAnswers", mappedBy="country", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $ccdbServicesAnswers;


// Specific Functions

    /**
     * Get ccdbServicesAnswers.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAnswersOfCategory($categoryID)
    {

        return $this->getCcdbServicesAnswers()->filter(function(CcdbServicesAnswers $answer) use($categoryID) {
            return $answer->getQuestion()->getCategory()->getId() == $categoryID;
        });
    }
```

And here is my create form function in my controller:

```
private function createCountryEditForm(Countries $entity, $categoryID)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(countriesCCDBServicesAnswersType::class, $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('updateCountryCcdbServicesAnswers', array('countryID' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'categoryID' => $categoryID,
    ));

    $form->add('submit', submitType::class, array('label' => 'Update', 'attr' => array('class' => 'hidden')));

    return $form;
}
```

**[UPDATE 20/11/2018]**

Here is what I did so far. This work but I would prefer a cleaner solution which deals with this filter with a where clause at database level and which would be more DRY. Doing this at the conroller level means that I have to do it everywhere I need this filter.

```
private function createCountryEditForm(Countries $entity, $categoryID)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(countriesCCDBServicesAnswersType::class, $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('updateCountryCcdbServicesAnswers', array('countryID' => $entity->getId(), 'categoryID' => $categoryID)),
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'categoryID' => $categoryID,
    ));

    $answers = $form->get('ccdbServicesAnswers')->getData();


    foreach ($answers as $answer) {

        if($answer->getQuestion()->getCategory()->getId() != $categoryID) {
            $answers->removeElement($answer);
        }

    }

    $form->get('ccdbServicesAnswers')->setData($answers);

    $form->add('submit', submitType::class, array('label' => 'Update', 'attr' => array('class' => 'hidden')));

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use filter in your entity. You should manually fetch answers using DQL.
Fetch array of entities and pass it to your form with CollectionType.

```
use cwt\psmdbBundle\Entity\CcdbServicesAnswers;
use cwt\psmdbBundle\Form\countriesCCDBServicesAnswersType;

// ....
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('a')
    ->from(CcdbServicesAnswers::class, 'a')
    ->where('
        country = :country
        AND category = :category
    ')
    ->setParameters([
        'country' => $country,
        'category' => $category
    ]);

$answers = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

$this->createForm(countriesCCDBServicesAnswersType::class, [
    'AnswersOfCategory' => $answers
]);
```

You could encapsulate fetching of required data to repository:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository